# Can anyone help me find this "Object reference not set" exception?

Tags: wcf, trace

[Traces.svclog](http://www.jsmunroe.com/Traces.svclog)

This is a service trace file that I've taken to try to catch a null reference exception.  You can see from the stack trace that this exception is occurring inside the `System.ServiceModel` namespace.  Is there something I can change in my web.Config, that would enable me to track down this exception's cause?  I'm at a loss. I'm currently using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726.aspx) diagnostics configuration.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the RIA domain services hosting code. Can you provide more information about your scenario?

Comment: On the server, I was converting my LINQ to SQL query to an 'IEnumerable' by calling 'AsEnumerable' against it.  Then I was projecting it into my POCO/DTO and then converting it back to 'IQueryable' by calling 'AsQueryable'.  I was doing this because some of the things I was doing against the query couldn't be done against IQueryable (they couldn't be transformed into SQL).  When I took this out, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server, I was converting my LINQ to SQL query to an 'IEnumerable' by calling 'AsEnumerable' against it. Then I was projecting it into my POCO/DTO and then converting it back to 'IQueryable' by calling 'AsQueryable'. I was doing this because some of the things I was doing against the query couldn't be done against IQueryable (they couldn't be transformed into SQL). When I took this out, it worked fine. I'd still like to know why it was crashing.

```
    [ProjectManagerAuthorization]
    public IQueryable<ProjectSummary> GetMachiningProjects()
    {
        var ret = (from project in _dataContext.DAProjects
                   where project.Status == "purchased" ||
                       project.Status == "ready" ||
                       project.Status == "machining" ||
                       project.Status == "onhold" ||
                       project.Status == "machined"
                   select project).AsEnumerable();

        return (from project in ret
                select new ProjectSummary
                {
                    ID = GetProjectID(project),
                    ProjectNumber = project.ProjectNumber,
                    StoreNumber = project.StoreNumber,
                    ProjectName = project.ProjectName,
                    OwnerEmail = project.OwnerEmail,
                    SheetQuantity = project.SheetQuantity ?? 0.0f,
                    EdgeLength = project.EdgeLength ?? 0.0f,
                    Price = project.Price ?? 0.0m,
                    SheetMaterialDescription = GetProjectSheetStockDescription(project),
                    BandingMaterialDescription = GetProjectBandingStockDescription(project),
                    Status = (ProjectStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProjectStatus), project.Status, true),
                    SubmitDate = UtcNormalizeDateTime(project.SubmitDate),
                    PurchaseDate = UtcNormalizeDateTime(project.PurchaseDate),
                    UsingQueuedMachine = true,
                    QueuedMachineID = project.QueuedMachineID,
                    QueuedMachineOrder = LookupQueuedMachineOrder(project)
                }).AsQueryable();

    }
```